# Value detection from text content

Tags: nlp, spacy

I have an agreement pdf file. However it has some payment terms in random text (not in a fix format or style entered by the sales people)

here is an example of line of text "20% of the Custom Services Fees (USD 6,000) to be paid on execution of the agreement form and prior to project
kick-off "

I want to grab the % if available and an amount. There will be multiple line items like this so I need parse all of them from the entire text body of the PDF.

Can someone please advise?

Comment: Can you advised based on the sample line of text I provided?

Comment: Maybe try reading through the rule-based section in the spaCy docs. https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching

Answer (score 0):

You could use [winkNLP](https://github.com/winkjs/wink-nlp) to extract these. Here is a [working example using the sample text in the question on Runkit](https://runkit.com/sanjaya/610d63ffc6e439001a8748c8):

[image]

For handling PDF, refer to "[How to run NLP on a PDF file](https://dev.to/winkjs/how-to-run-nlp-on-a-pdf-file-5f5b)?" on dev.to.